# Same process, different state diagrams according to the pov

Tags: uml, state

I want to do a state diagram to represent a user logging in. As far as I understand things, it could be done from two points of view:

Object: States

- User: Logged in, Not logged in (perhaps Initialized and Destroyed too).
- System: Waiting for login, Verifying login, Error, Logged in.

Does this appear correct? Also, are multiple state diagrams like this really necessary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Necessary" depends on what aspect you are trying to document, but I would say no.

If you are in a specification phase (use case elaboration), I usually advise not to use state charts at all; I find that activities are better suited for this purpose. State charts, in my view, are better suited for design descriptions.

This is because activities focus on the flow itself and thus describe something from an external point of view, whereas state charts describe an internal flow in which some defined entity moves between different states.

When you do a state chart you must answer the questions "what is the thing that has a state?" and "what does each state mean to the thing?" (Replace 'thing' with 'part of the system' if you prefer.)

In your case, I would suggest that it is the user (strictly speaking, the user account) that has the state, not the system.

It's not clear from the question what the scenario is, but if we're talking about a typical OS user account, it should probably have states like Logged Out, Logged In, Expired and Locked.

If you do specifically want to model the system side as well, then you should probably break it down to a smaller part, such as a User Client (or Terminal, or whatever). In keeping with the above, the key question is "does the (whole) system behave differently when a user is logged in?" and presumably it doesn't. The User Client, rather than the whole system, would then have states you list.

But all else being equal, I would say that a state chart describing the login/logout cycle should focus on the user account.